# Getting 404 though my app is deployed

Tags: java, git, tomcat, jenkins, openshift

Jenkins shows that the build was successful (see log below) and I can see the war in
/app-root/runtime/repo/target/0.1-MVP

The tomcat webapps (jwboss/webapps)
contains only ROOT.war.

How I can navigate to my deployed app?
I am using the tomcat gear. Is there a server manager UI? (something like tomcat manager)
Don't know if it matters but I using Spring for my application

I tried:

```
<openshift_application_name>.rhcloud.com/<MY REST PATH>
<openshift_application_name>.rhcloud.com/<myWebAppName>/<MY REST PATH>
```

I am getting 404 on both

> http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar
>   (422 KB at 2925.7 KB/sec) [INFO] Packaging webapp [INFO] Assembling
>   webapp [initial] in
>   [/var/lib/openshift/52dbe400e0b8cdce430000d0/app-root/runtime/repo/target/0.1-MVP]
>   [INFO] Processing war project [INFO] Copying webapp resources
>   [/var/lib/openshift/52dbe400e0b8cdce430000d0/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]
>   [INFO] Webapp assembled in [531 msecs] [INFO] Building war:
>   /var/lib/openshift/52dbe400e0b8cdce430000d0/app-root/runtime/repo/target/0.1-MVP.war
>   [INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 1:37.456s [INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 19 09:44:11
>   EST 2014 [INFO] Final Memory: 19M/86M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated
>   because it does not exist.
>   + /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh @.rhcloud.com 'gear stop --conditional
>   --exclude-web-proxy --git-ref 086d26cc8c980ca3144fcf1b5a524d521e3758b5' Stopping gear... Stopping
>   jbossews cartridge Sending SIGTERM to jboss:410122 ... kill -9 410376
>   kill -9 410122
>   ++ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh @.rhcloud.com 'gear
>   create-deployment-dir'
>   + deployment_dir=2014-01-19_09-44-28.240
>   + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh
>   /var/lib/openshift/52dbe400e0b8cdce430000d0//app-deployments/current/metadata.json
>   @.rhcloud.com:app-deployments/2014-01-19_09-44-28.240/metadata.json
>   + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh
>   --exclude .git /var/lib/openshift/52dbe400e0b8cdce430000d0/app-root/runtime/repo/
>   @.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/repo/
>   + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh
>   /var/lib/openshift/52dbe400e0b8cdce430000d0/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
>   @.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
>   + rsync --delete-after -az -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh
>   /var/lib/openshift/52dbe400e0b8cdce430000d0/app-root/runtime/dependencies/
>   @.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/dependencies/
>   + /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh @.rhcloud.com 'gear remotedeploy
>   --deployment-datetime 2014-01-19_09-44-28.240' Preparing build for deployment Deployment id is 2e006237 Activating deployment
>   + tmp=/var/lib/openshift//jbossews//tmp
>   + '[' -d /var/lib/openshift//jbossews//tmp ']'
>   + for d in '$tmp/*'
>   + '[' -d '/var/lib/openshift//jbossews//tmp/*' ']'
>   ++ ls /var/lib/openshift//app-root/runtime/repo//webapps
>   + '[' '' ']' Starting jbossews cartridge Found 127.13.77.129:8080 listening port Archiving artifacts Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: What does your pom.xml look like?

Answer (score 1):

Check your pom.xml to make sure that you have an openshift profile like the one that is shown here:https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossews/template/pom.xml

Or else openshift doesn't know what to do with the war file once it's built.

According to this error: [WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist